# how to model unbalanced data in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, supervised-learning

i am using a data set that has highly unbalanced data(Y=5% and N=95%) the data set has 3000 unique records. To select features I have used information gain. and then applied random forest with percentage split of 66.
Correctly Classified Instances                        96.1698 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances                      3.8302 %

=== Confusion Matrix ===

a----- b   <-- classified as

901  11 |   a = N

26  28 |   b = Y

Additionally, I have tried SMOTE filter but that does not change much of anything(getting very similar results.) i applied SMOTE filter to an extent where the instances of N and Y become almost equal.

Is there a possibility that the data is over-fitted? Is there a better approach than this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

From my humble experience, Unbalanced data can be handle at the data level and algorithmic level. What happen in SMOTE is the algo try to rebalance the data by replicating or over sampling the minority class data, which I think should be used carefully since there is possibility of overfitting. Have you try Hellinger Distance Decision Tree(HDDT) from this link https://www3.nd.edu/~nchawla/papers/DMKD11.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Classification rate does not make sense under Inbalanced data, perhaps sensitivity or specificity is better indicator. Other than that, information gain will suffer a lot since it use class count compared to Hellinger distance which is more robust to skewed data. Hope my humble comments will help.